# SQL Select Left Join two ON condition

Tags: sql, mysql, left-join

I am using MySQL and have the following tables :

Table user

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | One |
| 2 | Two |
| 3 | Three |
| 4 | Four |
| 5 | Five |

Table job

| number | Desc | loggedby | updatedby |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Job 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | Job 2 | 4 | 4 |
| 3 | Job 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | Job 4 | 3 | 1 |
| 5 | Job 5 | 1 | 5 |

Desired output

| number | Desc | loggedby | updatedby |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Job 1 | Two | One |
| 2 | Job 2 | Four | Four |
| 3 | Job 3 | One | Three |
| 4 | Job 4 | Three | One |
| 5 | Job 5 | One | Five |

This is what I try:

`SELECT job.*, user.name FROM job  LEFT JOIN user ON job.loggedby = user.id AND job.updatedby = user.id`

But the result mostly is null.

Please advise.

Comment: Join twice! One time for loggedby, and one time for updatedby.

Comment: you can join the same table twice but make sure to give a unique alias.

Answer (score 7):

You can simply join the same table twice .but make sure to give them a unique alias.

```
SELECT
  job.number,
  job.Desc,
  loggedbyuser.name AS loggedby,
  updatedbyuser.name AS updatedby
FROM job
LEFT JOIN user AS loggedbyuser ON job.loggedby = loggedbyuser.id
LEFT JOIN user AS updatedbyuser ON job.updatedby = updatedbyuser.id
```